# 1996-2006 Point and Click Website with Arcimboldo Painting Puzzle

Tags: story-identification, video-games, solar-system

**Platform**: Web
**Genre**: Puzzle/Point and Click
**Original Release**: Yes
**Estimated year of release**: 1996 to 2006
**Audience**: All. No nudity nor gore. Puzzles were solvable by kids but difficult.
**Locale**: Text on the site was all in English, though there wasn't much text. It was very visually driven.
**Graphics/art style**: Basic graphics. Not pixellated. But not HD either. Muted/darker color palette.

**Notable gameplay mechanics**: This game was the *entire website*, not just a game on a games site. It was themed/based in a solar system (may not have been our solar system).

You navigated between planets, each planet having different puzzles.

Two puzzles I distinctly recall:

- Arrange food to form a face (similar to the [paintings by Arcimboldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Arcimboldo#Four_Seasons))
- Set variables for a variant of [Conway's Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) with predator and prey.

**End-goal**: As far as I know, the goal was to complete a puzzle on each planet. I never completed it, so there could be more.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the science fiction or fantasy aspects of the game?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Flying from planet to planet solving problems seems reasonably sci-fi-ish

Comment: @Valorum:
Fair enough. I wasn't certain whether it was saying that there was a character navigating between planets or if it was a "click on Jupiter to access the Game of Life puzzle" with the planets basically just being theming on the website.